# Wordpress Loop - Rollover on Images

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

A lot of people have Wordpress right. I'm trying to adjust the code in the loop so that the thumbnails display three things on hover:

1. Post title
2. Twenty words of content with a "read more" link
3. Date of posting

Right now, I have them all displayed with a responsive grid (which works fine), but there is something wrong with the hover functionality. I haven't quite figured out how to assign styles within php tags. I tried to find a code online for what I need and only found plugins.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

CSS:

```
.attach_hover {
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;}
.attach_hover:hover {
    opacity:.5;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:-3;
}
.attach_text {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bolder;
    z-index:-1;
    float:left;
    width:75%;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 51px;
}
```

PHP/HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>  
<div class="col-sm-6" style="max-height:200px">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                    
    $image_src = the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size', array( 'class' => "attach_hover" ) );
    echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
    echo '</a>';
    $content = get_the_content();
    echo '<div class="attach_text">'; 
    $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 20, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"> ...Read More</a>' );
    $the_title = get_the_title();
    echo $trimmed_content;
    echo '</div>'; 
}?>
            </div><div class="col-sm-6" style="max-height:200px;">
<h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
            </div>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: `but there is something wrong with the hover functionality` Can you tell us what's wrong in actually ?

Comment: My apologies, the issue is that the 3 items I want to appear on hover are not contained within the attachment. They appear above and below. And there is a broken image icon above the attachment. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
The broken image icon was coming from here:

```
 echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
```

I also needed absolute positioning for the container that reveals on hover (.posttext), and I had to eliminate the second line of responsive bootstrap scaffolding. It was narrowing everything into one column:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="max-height:200px;">.
```

Lastly, I added p class assignments to elements of .posttext. These are .posthead .postdate and .postcontent. The head, date and content all had a position within the container.

It could still use tweaking, but it's a functional/responsive layout, allowing you to hover over post attachments in your loop and reveal:
    1. Post title
    2. Twenty words of content with a "read more" link
    3. Date of posting

---

CSS:

```
    .row {
    clear: both;}
.postloop {
    opacity:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
.posttext {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index:3;
    width: 96%;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
     background:rgb(255,255,255);  
    background: transparent\9;  
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000,endColorstr=#66000000);  
    zoom: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.posttext:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
 }
.posthead{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bolder;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    height: 60%;
}
.postdate{
    color:black;
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -1px;
    display: block;
}
.postcontent{
    color:black;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40%;
}
.readmore {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

PHP/HTML:

```
     <div class="row">
                <?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6"> 
            <?php
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">'; 
echo '<div class="posttext">';
echo '<p class="posthead">';
the_title();
echo '</p><p class="postdate">';
    the_date('F jS, Y');
echo '</p><p class="postcontent">';
    $content = get_the_content();
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 10,"...".'<p class="readmore"> <a href="'. get_permalink() .'">Read More</a>' );
echo $trimmed_content;
echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</a>';
    }?> 
                </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```